# genstrings -SwiftUI not working for buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, localization

I'm trying to generate a strings file for my SwiftUI project. I'm running this command in my project directory:

`find . -name "*.swift" | xargs genstrings -SwiftUI -o resources/en.lproj`

However `genstrings` does not seem to catch strings in Buttons initializers.
For this view:

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello")

    Button("Tap me") {
        // action
    }

    Text("Hi")
}
```

The output .strings file will only contain:

```
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Hello" = "Hello";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Hi" = "Hi";
```

I know that I could write buttons this way instead to make it work:

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
    Text("Button")
})
```

But I find it annoying not to be able to use the convenience init.
So is this a bug in genstrings? Or did I miss something?
I know the manual only mentions `Text()` initializer in the `-SwiftUI` option description but I see it also works for `TextField`.

I also tried both `xcrun extractLocStrings` & `xcodebuild -exportLocalizations` => same behaviour.

Explicitly using `LocalizedStringKey` doesn't make genstrings work any better.

Comment: I am running in to the exact same issue. genstrings seems to *only* work with the `Text` initializer. It doesn't work with any other APIs that take a `LocalizedStringKey`, such as the `help` `View` modifier.

Answer (score -1):

Try and wrap the string in LocalizedStringKey:

```
Button(LocalizedStringKey("I matter internationally"), action: { print("I'm a big global deal!") })
```

Comment: Looking at the docs, Button takes a LocalizedStringKey the way your original post had it [Button docs @ Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/init(_:action:)-1asy). It might be a bug. Maybe double check the containing file is selected in the localized set.